# Module sqlite3 not found after using sys.path.append in python

Tags: python, django, sqlite, vagrant

I have the Django framework installed so sqlite3 should be implicitly installed.

When I am trying to access sqlite3 module by adjusting the PYTHONPATH in the interpreter like so:

```
sys.path.append('/opt/local/bin/')
import sqlite3
```

it gives the error:

```
ImportError: No module named sqlite3
```

sqlite3 exists in the specified path

```
icepdf$ ls /opt/local/bin/sqlite3
/opt/local/bin/sqlite3*
```

I couldn't find a sqlite3 module in any other place.
I also tried to print all modules I have access to by calling:

```
sys.path.append('/opt/local/bin/')
print help('modules')
```

but sqlite does not appear. I am doing the import wrong? The sqlite3 module should be in a different place? Thanks in advance!

I am using Mac OS X Yosemite system on a Vagrant Client and installed Django1.4.5 using mac ports. I am also using Python2.7 built-in for Mac

Comment: thank you for your prompt response. I am using python2.7 on a Mac OS X Yosemite. I installed sqlite3 alongside Django1.4.5 with mac ports. I will add this information to the post.

Answer (score 0):

The file in `/opt/local/bin` is - as the name implies - a binary file to run sqlite3 from the command line. It has nothing to do with Python.

Python includes an sqlite3 module in the standard library. You do not need to install anything or change sys.path to use it.

Comment: i understand the difference now. still , after using  **print help('modules')** i get some standard libraries but sqlite3 is not one of them.

Comment: Are you using the built-in Python, or did you install your own? If so how?

Comment: i am using built-in python2.7 from Mac. It is actually a virtual machine set-up with Vagrant, but i didn't install it by myself

Comment: Are you running OSX within the Vagrant client?

Comment: yes, both guest and host are same version of OS X: Yosemite